# Java out of memory error when doing substring on extremely large strings

Tags: java, string, out-of-memory, heap-memory

The following method throws an exception when the input string is too long (length > 200,000). The problem seems to be related to the use of substring(), After looking at some other posts I changed the usage to become `String str = new String( s.substring( i,i+k ) );` but the problem still occurs...Any idea why the memoery exception is still thrown? (I do not want to increase the heap size)

The method:

```
 private static Map<String,Integer> findSubString(String s, int k) {
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(  );
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - (k - 1); i++) {
        String str = new String( s.substring( i,i+k ) );
        if (map.containsKey( str )) {
            map.put( str, map.get( str ) + 1 );
        }
        else {
            map.put( str, 1 );

        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1969)
at Solution.findSubString(Solution.java:112)
```

Comment: What is the value of XmX ?

Comment: You can assume it to be sufficiently large, more than 64gb for eg. The problem is with the code.

Comment: The version is Java8.

Comment: First, remove new String. Substring in Java8 already returns new one.

Comment: Can you specify range of parameter k (min, max, avg)?

Comment: @sibnick min = 1, max = length of s (in which case the number of substring should only be one), avg - I don't really know.

Comment: I played a bit and could reproduce only with XmX near 16mb for 200000 length string and k in range 2-8. I don't think there are problems with this code. Strings need space, map entries need space. There are no memory leeks or smth.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker thanks very much for your effort. It's good to know that this code is optimised, which means my approach to the problem was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the following will be a better way.

`str = s.substring( i,i+k ).intern() ;`
Remove the `new String` part first and move the `String str` out of the loop. We somehow need to make sure that the string returned from `subString` is unique.
Using the `intern` makes Java reuse the same strings. A note for caution though. Using [intern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) will slow your code down.

It will save memory though.

Comment: This code does not produce duplicate strings (except short lived) As result intern operation has no effect

Comment: That is the best optimization i could think off.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
String str = new String( s.substring( i,i+k ) );
```

causes memory leak. You should avoid instantiations inside loops.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an invalid assumption when you say:

> You can assume it to be sufficiently large, more than 64gb for eg. The problem is with the code.

How many entries are there in the map and what size are they when it blows. Try adding some debug code like:

```
if (map.size() % 50000 == 0) {
            System.out.println(map.size());
}
```

And post more info. The input string size, the size of substrings, the last reported result, and Xmx value being used.